# apache2 osx virtual host serving same directory

Tags: mac-osx, apache-2.2, virtualhost

In httpd.conf

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

ServerName testsite.com:80
DocumentRoot /usr/share/web
<Directory /usr/share/web>
// usual stuff from documentation
</Directory>
```

Include httpd-vhost is uncommented

in httpd-vhost.conf

NameVirtualHost *

```
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "/usr/share/web/a"
  ServerName www.testsite.com
  ServerAlias testsite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "/usr/share/web/b"
  ServerName site.testsite.com
  ServerAlias site
</VirtualHost>
```

in /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 localhost testsite.com www.testsite.com site.testsite.com

if I goto site.testsite.com, testsite.com www.testsite.com
I get served the page from /usr/share/web

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf, you're specifically listening on port 80, but your virtual hosts are not specifying a port.

Change to the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

and in each of your `VirtualHost` containers:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Also, you're defining the same `ServerName` in `httpd.conf` and `httpd-vhost.conf` -- I recommend changing the one in httpd.conf to something else.